# Porting processing to actionscript 3 - understanding color data type

Tags: actionscript-3, processing, porting

Im trying to port a script from processing to as3. I dont know processing at all and I am having trouble understanding a specific line of code (processing):

```
color[] unsorted = new color[sortLength];
```

color seems to be a data type in processing but here the implementation looks more like an array. Is there some kind of color array data type that Im missing?

Comment: This seems like an array that is copied. The array's name is color[] but that has nothing to do with the color data type. Perhaps this array is filled with values of the color data type? See the reference: color c1 = color(204, 153, 0);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `color` type in Processing is essentially an `int`: `0xAARRGGBB`

You can also see that this is the type returned by the [color()](https://processing.org/reference/color_.html) function.

The above would translate to:

```
var sortLength:uint = 10;
var unsorted:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>(sortLength,true);
trace("unsorted",unsorted);
```

That is if you want to keep an efficient, fixed size list of the same type to mirror Processing behaviour as much as possible.

Otherwise `var unsorted:Array = new Array(sortLength);` should do.
(It will be a little less efficient since Array can holds multiple types, not just uint and the size is dynamic)

Comment: Thank you, that was kind of what I thought. Just so I understand processing: "color[] unsorted = " are we typecasting an array called unsorted to make room for 10 entries but only of the color type?
Same as you are doing with :Vector.<uint> ?

Comment: @DavidLamm Almost: you see it as type casting because you look at the Processing syntax as if it's as3 and it's not: it's java actually. In Java you don't use the `var` keyword, you just specify the variable type first. For example in as3 ```var myInt:int = 0;``` would be ```int myInt = 0;``` in Processing/java (even c/c++). Similarly ```var myIntArray:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>(10,true);``` would be ```int[] myIntArray = new int[10];``` in Processing). 
Long story short: yes, it's creating a fixed size array of the same type, but no, it's not typecasting. HTH